# I do not understand what 腰折れ懸念 means

Tags: meaning, translation, words, word-requests

I am a student of Japanese language, and while translating from an economic review text, I encountered this term 腰折れ懸念, which I tried looking up on the internet, but unfortunately with no results, if not Jisho.org giving me a translation which didn't seem appropriate for the kind of text I was translating from (腰折れ = bad poem).

 Could someone help me solve this? That's the phrase from where I took this expression:
だが、不安材料も多い。物価上昇の勢いほど所得が伸びず、個人消費には腰折れ懸念が残
る。積極的な賃上げの継続が消費底上げの大前提だといえる。

Answer (score 2):

腰折れ basically means "back bending" as the kanji suggest. It has several derivative meanings, one of which is "(economic) stall" or a sudden disruption of economic activities. This sense is explained as the second definition of this dictionary entry:

> ##### [腰折れ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%85%B0%E6%8A%98%E3%82%8C/)
>
> ２ 景気や経済活動が、成長・回復・現状維持の状態から、はっきりとした悪化の局面に転じること。「通貨危機が原因で、景気が―した」

The dictionary says 腰折れ (or 腰折れ歌) also refers to poorly connected and unskillful waka, but I personally was not aware of this obsolete meaning.